# Why is this syntax in Java valid?

Tags: java, syntax

Taken from [here](http://blogs.oracle.com/darcy/entry/project_coin_7u2_fixes), why is this syntax valid:

```
class X {
  class Y {
    Y(T a, Z b) {...}
  }

  public static void main(String... args) {
    // why is this valid? the second new looks confusing to me
    X<String>.Y<String> x1 = new X<String>().new Y<String>("",""); //ok
  }
}
```

Since when has this syntax (`new Foo().new Bar()`) been valid?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Since Java 1.1, apparently](http://www.public.iastate.edu/~java/docs/guide/innerclasses/html/innerclasses.doc.html) (thanks @emory).

Class "Y" is a non-static, [nested (inner) class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) of class "X".  As such, any instance of class "Y" must be constructed from an "outer" instance of class "X".

See also this article which describes nested classes well: http://blogs.oracle.com/darcy/entry/nested_inner_member_and_top

Comment: But isn't `new` an operator? This syntax makes it look like a method on `Foo`.

Comment: Okay, it is mentioned in that link. But it is weired that I hadn't seen this for years! Sigh!

Comment: This document, http://www.public.iastate.edu/~java/docs/guide/innerclasses/html/innerclasses.doc.html, suggests that prior to 1.1 there were no inner classes in java.

Comment: @KEverest: yes, "new" is an operator and this is a special case of its use which requires an "outer" object instance, hence looking like a method.

Comment: Basically, in every language operators are methods, and are replaced at compile by appropriate method calls (give or take a few things like arythmetics on basic types and such).

Comment: @KEverest the reason you have not seen it for years is probably because if Y is so tightly coupled to X that it makes sense for Y to be inside X, then it would also make sense to instantiate Y inside X in which case the syntax is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

Bacause java supporr the "inner class declaration". That means that we can define a class inside another class wich may can have a name (for your code, Y is the inner class inside the X class). Now, when you write "new Foo().newBar()" that means that first you cerate an object of Foo and when it is created is create the Bar object (defined as an inner class), the result is a Bar object returned.